# Como hacer un Update a dos tablas a la vez

Tags: mysqli, update

se puede hacer un UPDATE a dos tablas a la vez? Estoy haciendo esto pero evidentemente no funciona:

```
<?php
 $id = $_POST['eIdp'];
 $producto = $_POST['eidPr'];
 $factura = $_POST['eNumero'];
 $eFecha = $_POST['eFecha'];
 $eVencimiento = $_POST['eVencimiento'];
 $estado = $_POST['select2-1'];
 $tipo = $_POST['select2-4'];
 $total = $_POST['eTotal'];
 $referencia = $_POST['select2-3'];


//die()

 $results = "Update pedidos Set Numero='$factura', Fecha='$eFecha', Vencimiento='$eVencimiento', Estado='$estado', Producto='$producto', Tipo='$tipo', Total='$total', Referencia='$referencia' where id= " .$_POST['eIdp'];

"Update referencias Set estadoMaquina='$tipo' where referencia=  $referencia ";



  if ( !mysqli_query($mysqli, $results)) {
    die( 'Error: ' . mysqli_error() );
  }
 mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Tambien tengo que saber si se puede hacer un where con un campo así:

`where DI001 = DI001`

Comment: Eso no te puede funcionar porque la cadena $results no es correcta. te faltaria añadir la segunda cadena a la variable $results. Como tal se pueden hacer varias consultas seguidas, pero tienes que escribirlas correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

El fallo lo puedes tener aqui:

```
 $results = "Update pedidos Set Numero='$factura', Fecha='$eFecha', Vencimiento='$eVencimiento', Estado='$estado', Producto='$producto', Tipo='$tipo', Total='$total', Referencia='$referencia' where id= " .$_POST['eIdp'];

"Update referencias Set estadoMaquina='$tipo' where referencia=  $referencia ";
```

tienes que continuar escribiendo la cadena correspondiente. Por ej:

```
$results = "Update pedidos Set Numero='$factura', Fecha='$eFecha', Vencimiento='$eVencimiento', Estado='$estado', Producto='$producto', Tipo='$tipo', Total='$total', Referencia='$referencia' where id= " .$_POST['eIdp'];

$results.=";Update referencias Set estadoMaquina='$tipo' where referencia=  $referencia ";
```

Con esto, tu cadena $results tiene las dos consultas continuas.

Comment: Esto es correcto $results.=";Upadte.......     Ese punto después del $results? y el ; después de "

Comment: el .= es para concatenar variables. Es como si hubieras escrito $results = $results . "cadena".  Por otra parte, el ; antes del Update es para separar sentencias sql.

Comment: Por el momento no me funciona, los valores como este se puede hacer un WHERE?? where DI001 = DI001

Comment: Haz una cosa, pon despues el $results.= "..." un die($results);  Y vemos que te  ha generado. Asi sabremos si la consulta no esta del todo correcta.

Comment: No necesita ejecutar la consulta con una multi query?  Ejemplo: `$mysqli->multi_query($sql)`

Comment: eIdp: 1 
eidPr: 1
eNumero: 201801
eFecha: 2018-05-04
eVencimiento: 2018-09-16
select2-1: 1
select2-4: 2
eTotal: 100.00
select2-3: DI006

Comment: Perdona, sale todo en la misma linea :S

Comment: lo has puesto despues del $results.= "..." ?? el die($results) solo deberia mostrarte el texto de la consulta, no lo que pones en el comentario...

Comment: @MarioGuiber desconocia la existencia del multi-query. En principio es lo mismo, solo que multi-query te permite ver los resultados de cada sentencia sql, y lo que estamos haciendo solo sacaria el resultado de la ultima. Me parece mejor opcion la tuya.

Comment: Esta en el sitio correcto @Jakala pero al ser un modal no muestra nada

Comment: en ese caso, te toca ejecutar "lo que ejecuta" el modal, en una pestaña aparte, para ver el resultado :)

Comment: no hay otra forma, tengo que hacer muchisimo lio para preparar una pestaña a parte que cargue todo la inf

Answer (score 0):

Para armar dos consultas a la vez necesitas `mysqli_multi_query($link, $query)` para ejecutar los dos `UPDATE`

Ademas como dice @Jakala necesitas concatenar las consultas con `.=`

Tu código quedaría así:

```
<?php
     $id = $_POST['eIdp'];
     $producto = $_POST['eidPr'];
     $factura = $_POST['eNumero'];
     $eFecha = $_POST['eFecha'];
     $eVencimiento = $_POST['eVencimiento'];
     $estado = $_POST['select2-1'];
     $tipo = $_POST['select2-4'];
     $total = $_POST['eTotal'];
     $referencia = $_POST['select2-3'];

     $results = "Update pedidos Set Numero='$factura', Fecha='$eFecha', Vencimiento='$eVencimiento', Estado='$estado', Producto='$producto', Tipo='$tipo', Total='$total', Referencia='$referencia' where id= " .$_POST['eIdp'];

     $results.=";Update referencias Set estadoMaquina='$tipo' where referencia=  $referencia ";

     if ( !mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $results)) {
          die( 'Error: ' . mysqli_error() );
     }

     mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: Gracias @Mario Guiber esta forma la probe antés y no consigo que funcione. Es la misma que puso Jakala

Comment: @Miguel mira bien los campos de tu base de datos,  agregale comillas al campo ' $referencia'

Comment: @MoteCL le puse las comillas pero sigue sin ir. Pero nadie me respondio a si se puede hacer un where de este modo: where DI001 = DI001.  Eso también lo reconoce el where o solo numero??

Comment: El where en si, es correcto, y si, puedes hacerlo. Si `DI001` es un campo de tu tabla, debe reconocértelo directamente. Si por el contrario es una cadena, debes ponerlo entre comillas. En caso de comparar con numeros o booleanos, se puede directamente:  `where 5=5`,  `where true = true`...

Comment: @Miguel No un where asi `where DI001 = DI001` no funcionaria, la forma correcta seria de esta forma `where referencia = DI001`. El where reconoce numeros y letras

Comment: @MoteCL y Jakala pues si, si lo reconoce entonces no se muy bien que es lo que pasa.

Comment: Me podéis ayudar por favor! sigo sin solucionar el problema. Gracias @MoteCL

Comment: @Miguel y si realizas un solo update